# How to combine a formula with text in one cell?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, concatenate

My spreadsheet contains data divided into weeks in a year and I would like to combine the following two pieces of information in one cell:

- `=ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())`
- Calendar week

'Calendar week' being the name of the whole column is just a text that I would like to maintain and the week number would be a help to see what week it is (either before or after the 'Calendar week').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- shorter:

  ```
  =ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())&"Calendar week"
  ```
- or with space perhaps (?):

  ```
  =ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY())&" Calendar week"
  ```

Comment: Thanks for better formula! Instead of a space I have used "fill range" twice so it's nicer to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found one way to do that. Of course, if there is any simpler/faster/better way, do let me know

```
=CONCAT(ISOWEEKNUM(TODAY()); "Calendar week")
```